# What is the file 0000000000000001.db?

Tags: android, database, cordova

I am trying to use a pre populated sqlite database in my android app using phonegap. Following [this blog](http://gauravstomar.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence%20%28Gaurav%20S%20Tomar%20%3a%20Bootstrapping%20Intelligence%29) I understood how to begin. Now I can open the database, my tables are there but it's not populated, all my selects are empty, and I think the problem lies on this file 0000000000000001.db. Can someone explain why it's needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file 0000000000000001.db is my database. The file databases.db relates the database file (0000000000000001.db) with the database name. If you have more databases in that app they will be ordered: 0000000000000002.db,0000000000000003.db,0000000000000004.db etc..

Comment: this 2^4 means 16_digit.db file name is conventional ?
we can change it ?

Comment: I don't think you can change it. Not sure if it's conventional or not.